# Linux Kernel cannot find USB Stick to use as root FS

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, root-filesystem

I have a USB stick with a Basic Linux/Busybox distro from scratch.
I use extlinux as my bootloader.

In Qemu everything works fine and I can boot without problems by typing in the following command into the syslinux prompt:

`/bzImage rw root=/dev/sda1`

However on real Hardware I get the syslinux Prompt, but the kernel panics as it cannot mount root because only the internal SSD shows up as valid Options for the `root=` parameter.

The problem is that the Kernel and the root filesystem it should mount are on the USB Stick, which is not recognized by the Kernel.

What I already tried:

- Using an external SSD: also not recognized by the Kernel.
- compiling and using the stable version of the Kernel (6.7.8): just a black screen after syslinux

What do I have to input in the `root=` parameter?

Which configs do I need to set in the Kernel?

Kernel Version: 6.8-rc6 Hardware: MacBook Pro 2012